# AspectJ: Trace objects that their class type has been tagged with the Java annotation @logging

Tags: aspectj, java.util.logging

I am new to aspectJ and i need to create an aspect which traces objects with the @logging annotation.

I have created a pointcut but i get a warning on the @logging annotation.

```
 pointcut tracedObjects(Object v): target(v) &&  call(@logging new(..)) && !within(BasicLogger);
```

The warning is "no match for this type name: logging [Xlint:invalidAbsoluteTypeName]"
Any ideas why?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to use the absolute path to `@logging`, so something more along the lines of

```
pointcut tracedObjects(Object v): target(v) &&  call(@com.yourpackage.logging new(..)) && !within(BasicLogger);
```

Its likely you'll need to do this for BasicLogger as well.

Comment: I agree. Either that or something like `@*..logging` if you prefer a wildcard solution or have multiple, semantically similar logging annotations in different packages.

Comment: i've managed to do it with execution similarly to what Niall have done but the advise is been defined on the top of the class. That's quite not right because i need the position of the object that is created. When i tried with call it did not get advised at all.. :/

Comment: There are fundamental semantic differences between `call` and `execution`. You need to know them. Please read some basic literature on AspectJ. As an alternative, please provide some more code. And please clarify in better English what you mean by "position of the object that is created" and by "advice has been defined on top of the class".